# Understanding parameters passed to abstract function

Tags: php

I was just going through the code of this observer pattern **[HERE](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/php)**, and i came across the below line of code:

```
abstract class AbstractObserver {
    abstract function update(AbstractSubject $subject_in);
}
```

The very first function in that snippet actually ,  now i am very new to PHP, I know javascript , but i am not so good in PHP , now what on earth are these parameters passed to the abstract function:

```
AbstractSubject $subject_in
```

?? What is this ?

Answer (score 1):

Its a single parameter that it's typed, meaning that that function can only recieve an instance of `AbstractSubject` as the parameter.

Note that the words are not separated by a comma, but a space, meaning that the first word (`AbstractSubject`) defines the type of the parameter (second word, `$subject_in`) the method may receive, if you pass a value of any other type than an instance of `AbstractSubject`, you will get an exception raised.

So, an implementation of the given method should look something like this:

```
class MyObserver extends AbstractObserver
{
    public function update(AbstractSubject $subject_in)
    {
        //Your implementation of the method goes here.
    }

}
```

Comment: you seem to be trying to explain me .. thank you, you are good guy , but me , new to PHP , so please be the elaborate .. ;)

Comment: just look the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/it/language.oop5.typehinting.php) about Type Hinting